# Android - NoClassDefError on Joda time functions

Tags: java, android, exception, jodatime, noclassdeffounderror

So far all of my Joda time API functions were working fine. The only thing I did that I suppose could change that is I updated my project to use Android 4.4.2

Anyone have any idea how to fix it? I've already tried cleaning the project and it did not work. I am not sure what else I can do to solve this as I did not find many people with the same issue...

here is my simple function that uses the Joda Time API:

```
DateTime getCurrentDate(){
    return new DateTime();
}
```

Here is the error log:

```
  05-08 15:50:08.654: E/AndroidRuntime(9938): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  05-08 15:50:08.654: E/AndroidRuntime(9938): Process: com.example.jfitnessfunctiontester, PID: 9938
  05-08 15:50:08.654: E/AndroidRuntime(9938): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.joda.time.DateTime
  05-08 15:50:08.654: E/AndroidRuntime(9938):   at analyse.WalkingAnalyse.getCurrentDate(WalkingAnalyse.java:67)
  05-08 15:50:08.654: E/AndroidRuntime(9938):   at analyse.WalkingAnalyse.enterActivity(WalkingAnalyse.java:85)
  05-08 15:50:08.654: E/AndroidRuntime(9938):   at activities.EnterActivityActivity$3.onClick(EnterActivityActivity.java:86)
  05-08 15:50:08.654: E/AndroidRuntime(9938):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
  05-08 15:50:08.654: E/AndroidRuntime(9938):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
  05-08 15:50:08.654: E/AndroidRuntime(9938):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
  05-08 15:50:08.654: E/AndroidRuntime(9938):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  05-08 15:50:08.654: E/AndroidRuntime(9938):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
  05-08 15:50:08.654: E/AndroidRuntime(9938):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
  05-08 15:50:08.654: E/AndroidRuntime(9938):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  05-08 15:50:08.654: E/AndroidRuntime(9938):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  05-08 15:50:08.654: E/AndroidRuntime(9938):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
  05-08 15:50:08.654: E/AndroidRuntime(9938):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
  05-08 15:50:08.654: E/AndroidRuntime(9938):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this port [joda-time-android](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android) created for android.

Comment: Sorry. This did nothing for me. What am I supposed to do here? I have no idea even how to include this in my project.

UHhh... I think I'm going to cry

Answer (score 0):

After about a half an hour of desperately messing around with the libraries in the project doing everything all the other related topics told me to, somehow it worked again.

I really don't know what I did, but perhaps if anyone has this problem in the future. Do all that libs related stuff as well as opening and closing eclipse :P